# Identify if transaction is committed

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions

In my application, I encountered a scenario where while inserting in db, runtime exception was thrown which rolled back the entire transaction, which is expected.

But how do we identify from Controller that when transaction was successful committed for got rolled back to send the response accordingly back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by (trying and) catching the(/any) runtime exception ... in your controller!?

Comment: if this is not sufficient, you can [gain "complete control" of the (current) transaction](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management), but have to propagate the status to the controller...

Comment: Consider cleaner code with this, instead of try/ catch
```
    @ControllerAdvice
    @RestController
    public class RestExceptionHandler {

      @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
      @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
      public ResponseEntity<String> exceptionHandler(Exception e, WebRequest request) {
        log.error(request.getDescription(false));
        log.error(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase() + e.getMessage(), e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.toString(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

Comment: Will the transaction get rolledback if I am explicitly throwing Runtime exception?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the status of the current transaction using

```
TransactionStatus status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
```